# How to resolve Microsoft SQL geography type dependency on AppHarbor

Tags: sql-server-2008, appharbor

I am trying to deploy my web service on AppHarbor through GitHub. My web service is using NHibernate.Spatial, which has Microsoft.SQLServer.Types version 10.0.0.0 as a dependency. This assembly is, if I understand correctly, installed along with SQL Server 2008. When I run my web service on my development computer, on which I have SQL Server 2008 installed, the service runs without trouble, but when I deploy to AppHarbor I get the following exception:

> "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,
>   Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

As I already build my own version of NHibernate.Spatial.MsSql2008, the assembly from which the dependency derives, I have simply tried copying the required dll into the bin folder when building this project, by setting the reference property Copy Local to true. This is also reflected in the web service bin folder which is pulled by AppHarbor through Git. This didn't help though and my guess is that my web service is looking for the dependency in a different folder than bin.

How do I make the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly available on AppHarbor? As the exception states, this might also be caused by possible missing dependencies of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, but how do I find if this is the case, and again, how do I make the dependencies of Microsoft.SqlServer.Types available on AppHarbor?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you downvoted this question (and 4 other random questions I've posted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a [NuGet package with the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types assembly](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types). You can use this in combination with [NuGet package restore](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/2/06/use-nuget-package-restore-to-avoid-pushing-packages-to-appharbor) on AppHarbor.

Comment: I'm able to make the topic of each article work individually, but I'm unsure of how to make it work together. I've tried quite alot by now, but I still havn't seen any change at all to the exception being thrown. I've never really used NuGet package restore, so can you point me in a direction on how to make this work with the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types package?

Comment: Install the NuGet package, enable NuGet package restore as mentioned in the blog post and you're good to go.